# Python: doing math operation on element of subsets of a nested list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am a beginner in coding and I have a problem regarding doing mathematical operation on element of a nested list. I have this nested list q:

```
import random

point = list (range(1000))
f = ("f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", "f5", "f6")
q = []
for i, x1 in enumerate(point):
    q.append([])
    for x2 in f:
        q[i].append(random.randint(100, 1500))
```

I have also:

```
t = 10
capacity = 1000
```

Suppose to call x a single element of a subset of the list; instead of x I want to have `abs(int(-t/(capacity//x)))`

How can I create this new nested list?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's `f1`, `f2`, ... ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then come back and rephrase your question

Comment: I think you should have a look at `numpy`. There you can do mathematical operation on entire arrays or matrices of numbers e.g. `X = np.array([1, -2, 3]); Y = abs(X) + 5`, which would give you `array([6, 7, 8])`

Comment: _Note_: In _Py27_ `list (range(1000))` is equivalent to `range(1000)` so you could use the 2nd form.

Comment: Thank you @tobias_k . It can be sound strange, but I was looking for a solution that doesn't require the use of numpy or other packages for scientific computing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A recursive solution is more general as it works on arbitrarily nested lists:

```
# Define function that operates on a single number
def func(x):
    return abs(int(-t/(float(capacity)/x)))   

# Define another function to apply it recursively
def rec_func(x, f):
    # Base case: apply function on numbers (floats or integers)
    if isinstance(x, (float, int)):
        return f(x)
    # Recursive call
    elif isinstance(x, list):
        return [rec_func(el, f) for el in x]
    else:
        raise AttributeError

result = rec_func(q, func)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were looking for:

```
from __future__ import division
import random

point = range(1000)
f = ("f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", "f5", "f6")

t = 10
capacity = 1000

q = [[abs(int(-t/(capacity/random.randint(100, 1500)))) for _ in range(len(f))] for _ in point]
```

Comment: Sorry if my question is not enirely clear but English is not my first language. However i don't want to modify the list q; I want to create a new list.